# Accessing a remote drive on from a remote computer with psexec

Tags: batch-file, remote-access, psexec

I'm trying to access through a process on remote computer a remote drive ( The remote drive is on a 3rd computer) using this batch command:

```
call c:\psexec.exe \\Some.Ip.Address -u administrator -p password i -s "c:\SomeFolder\Another.bat"
```

The remote drive has different credentials than the remote computer.
The process I'm trying to run - runs successfully but when it tries to access the remote drive it fails.

What am I doing wrong? Do i have to give the remote drive's credentials  as well, and if so - how?

Answer (score 1):

The command for accessing a remote drive is

`\\Some.Ip.Address\\Drive.Letter+$`